# jQuery mobile changePage issue

Tags: jquery, mobile

This may be a simple problem but it is being stubborn.

I am trying to load a php page that does a mysql query based on the data that is in the url via the get array.

```
    $.mobile.changePage("./info.php", {
    transition: "slideup",
    type: "get",
    data: 'diskID='+diskID

    });
```

It appears to go to the info.php page with the correct data in the url but only says "undefined".

If i refresh the page it reads the data out of the get array, and everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: oh yeah, this is jQuery Mobile rc1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading info.php directly with that data?

Whenever that issue came up, it was usually due to a php error.

If that isn't the issue. Try this instead:

```
$.mobile.changePage("./info.php?diskID="+diskID, { transition: "slideup" });
```